# problem with transit details from steps Google API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, direction, google-directions-api

I try to get details for a route with transit mode. When I try to read the results from legs ( result['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps']['transit_details']['departure_time']['value'] ), I get a departure time for the transit in a different date and time.

for example,
with this url request:

url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=32.324455,34.977291&destination=32.07806,34.802639&mode=transit&transit_mode=train&departure_time=1579008600&key= MyAPI'

I get that the departure time at the first train changed to 15/1/2020 3:47 , however the request departure time was 14/1/2020 13:30.

Comment: I get a train on 2020/01/14 if I add `alternatives=true` to the request, or if I remove the `transit_mode` from the request. If you believe this is an issue you should talk to Google support and report a bug, [which you did already](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147566205) as Stackoverflow is not Google support.

Comment: Many thanks, using alternatives=true helps to deal with this bug in this case. I wrote to Google Support to check this issue.